# What tool can make a nice 3D image of a via?

Tags: pcb, via, 3d

I found this graphic somewhere on the web, but now I need to create a similar illustration for some training, but with a 16 layer board having traces coming in on other layers etc.

[image: via in 3D]

What is the easiest/fastest/cheapest tool to do this? What tool was used for this graphic?

Comment: Unless you want to model a specific layout, maybe you could use Sketchup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can zoom into your board in the 3D view in Altium:

[image]

I changed the view settings to scale up the board thickness (otherwise you can't get a good look inside) and to color the structures by layer.

[image]

To remove copper from un-used layers like so:
[image]

In 2D layout mode, open the via properties and select "Full-Stack" in the Diameters panel:
[image]

Set the diameter to 0 for desired layer:
[image]

Comment: Can you remove non-functional pads for the vias in the 3D view?

Comment: @RolfOstergaard Not that I know of. I'm not sure how you'd tell Altium what is supposed to be functional or not.

Comment: It's a common thing to do so I am sure you can remove non-functional pads somehow, but other tools I know of does it only while generating the Gerber files. That's why I ask if you can create a 3D view without the non-functional pads in place.

Comment: @RolfOstergaard I think I mis-understood you before. Does my edit help?

Comment: Very nice! Now I just need to find someone to do this for me on a given 16L stackup for two cases: Both with the via trace entering at the top layer - one with exit at L3 and one with exit at L15.

Answer (score 2):

High end EDA tools, such as Altium, have 3D visualization (nowadays).

Mechanical 3D CAD tool, such as SolidWorks or AutoDesk Inventor can create an image like that.  The image below was done in SolidWorks (by me).

[image]

An artistic  3D animation package should be able to create an image like that too.

Comment: Beautiful diagram, why "silk screen" not "solder-mask".

Comment: Thanks - can you say for sure that Altium can show this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently found "ZofzPCB" (https://www.zofzpcb.com/).  It seems to do a fairly stellar job of making a PCB look absolutely beautiful and geometrically accurate.

I've been using it at work to sanity-check Gerber files (it's natively supported format) before manufacture.

In particular it does a good job of showing layer connectivity for vias, and PTH features.  Thermal reliefs of all kinds are nicely displayed.

One of my favourite features is the "Spread" layers view, where it explodes the PCB and elongates all the vias to reveal all net / layer / plane connections.

FD: (I'm not affiliated in any way with ZofsPCB software)

Comment: Wow, ZofsPCB looks good!